# Implementing a while loop without interrupting the bot's main event loop

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am in the middle of having two of my bots interfacing with each other via a ZMQ server, unfortunately that also requires a second loop for the receiver, so i started looking around the web for solutions and came up with this:

```
async def interfaceSocket():
    while True:
        message = socket.recv()
        time.sleep(1)
        socket.send(b"World")
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as:')
    print(client.user.name)

client.loop.create_task(interfaceSocket())
client.run(TOKEN)
```

I basically added the interfaceSocket function to the event loop as a task as another while loop so i can constantly check the socket receiver while also checking the on_message listener from the discord bot itself but for some reason, the loop still interrupts the main event loop. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `interfaceSocket` is technically a task, it doesn't await anything in its `while` loop and uses blocking calls such as `socket.recv()` and `time.sleep()`. Because of that it blocks the whole event loop while it waits for something to happen.

If `socket` refers to a ZMQ socket, you should be using the ZMQ [asyncio interface](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.asyncio.html), i.e. use `zmq.asyncio.Context` to create a `zmq.asyncio.Socket` instead of. Then `interfaceSocket` can use `await` and become a well-behaved coroutine:

```
async def interfaceSocket():
    while True:
        message = await socket.recv()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await socket.send(b"World")
```

Comment: I see what you mean, while this does work I get a TypeError of 'object bytes cannot be used in await expression' not quite sure what that means though, it happens on the socket receive line

Comment: @Myronaz The prerequisite for the code to work is that `socket` be an instance of `zmq.asyncio.Socket`. If that is not the case, you cannot await it. How do you obtain the `socket`?

Comment: I obtain the socket through `context = zmq.Context()` and then `socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)`

Comment: @Myronaz You should be using `zmq.asyncio.Context` instead, which is the "context for creating asyncio-complatible Sockets". Please refer to the [documentation](https://pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/zmq.asyncio.html) also linked from the question.